# How do relative paths to ejs templates work?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am trying to render some ejs. I'm not using any frameworks. So right now I have an ejs navigation bar template and a template for a random other site (in this example it is just a form).
My directory:

- root

  - rendered (cache for already rendered sites)
  - sites (ejs templates for sites)

    - form.ejs
    - test.ejs (template I am trying to insert into form.ejs)
  - templates (ejs templates for reusable stuff like the nav-bar)

    - bar.ejs
  - server.js (logic for the server: including rendering of ejs)

So now comes the actual question: How do I reference an other ejs template in an ejs template? The [docs](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/main/README.md) say:

```
%- include('user/show') %>
```

Includes ./user/show.ejs into the template (As I understood it relative to the current ejs file if no absolute path is given)

```
<% include user/show %>
```

is not supported after v3.0, but would have done (almost) the same.
So now I thought I could just do

```
<%- include('test') %>
```

in my form.ejs, but it throws an error:

```
Could not find the include file "test.ejs"
```

So I wondered what was going on and included the absolute Path to the file and voila it works.
I was curious so i included

```
<%- process.cwd(); %>
```

into form.ejs and that return the root directory probably because it is being executed from server.js.
So now the question is: How do I get relative paths? Do I have to create a variable at runtime with the root directory and add that to my include paths like this? (even this wouldn't be relative)

```
const root = process.cwd(); //inside server.js
<%- include(root+'/sites/test.ejs') %>
```

This seems inelegant. What am I missing? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm guilty of RTFM: It didn't work before, because i had to set the `views` option in my ejs.render(str, data, options). With

```
ejs.render(contents.toString(),null,{views:["./sites"]}); //in server.js
<%- include('test') %> // in form.ejs ('test.ejs' works as well)
```

It now renders, but still, the path is relative to the one set in views.
Ok that's a workaround and after digging a bit more i found this line from the [docs](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/main/README.md) literally a line after what i originally posted:

> You must specify the `filename` option for the template with the
> include call unless you are using `renderFile()`.

`renderFile()` is asynchronous, so that wouldn't work for me. So finally the solution is to modify my original ejs.render function:

```
html = ejs.render(contents.toString(),null,{filename: ejspath}); //ejspath being the path to the ejs file to render
//contents is the contents of the ejs file
```

This Method works with paths like ../templates.bar inside of form.ejs